# MVVM Light Global Message registration?

Tags: mvvm-light

I am using MVVM light to build my application and so far it has given excellent results. but I have this one small issue that i need to resolve.

Is there a way to globally register message listeners for each View model before they are initiated by the view. Something like a GlobalMessageRegistrationClass() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the MVVM Light tool kit, then you have to create a base Videmodel class which  should be inherited from the MVVM Light tool kit class "ViewModelbase". Then all your view model class  should be inherited from your custom viewmodel base class instead of MVVM light tool kit base class "ViewModelbase". In constructor of custom view model base class you can register for messages.